# vertical alignment and float: left

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble understanding the `float` attribute. I have this code :

```css
#p1 {
  border: solid black 3px
}
```

```html
<p id="p1" style="float:left">Paragraph 1</p>
<a href="https://facebook.com" style="float:left"> This is a link </a>
<p>Paragraph 2</p>
<p>Paragraph 3</p>
```

Now, the result I expect is to have Paragraph1 in the first line, then the link next to it, then  Paragraph2 next to the link and Paragraph3 in the second line. But the result that this code gives me is this:

[image]

Comment: Is this what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/nra3dpvd/ ?

Comment: Yes that is what I want. But you can explain what is the problem in my code ? I mean why does the link and paragraph2 show up before
paragraph1?

Comment: if you open the dev tools in your browser, and hover over paragraph 1 you'll see why. these are always useful for checking out layout issues

Comment: You could have a nice read in this [All about floats](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/) article.

Comment: @Kockar By "show up **before**" you mean "above" right? That's `<p>`'s default margin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're getting seemingly strange results is due to the border, margin, and padding on the elements that you're floating.

By default, floated elements will float up to the top and left/right of their container element, displacing whatever elements are there already. In the case of your floated elements, they are floated left, and they push "Paragraph 2" over to the right. If you examine Paragraph 1, you'll see that it has the browser's default styling on it, which is 16px margins top and bottom (on my browser, Chrome). Look at the "this is a link" element, and you'll see it has no margins. Paragraph 1 is thus being pushed down 19px by its top margin and the 3px top border, while "this is a link" can float up to rest against the top of the enclosing element.

If you want paragraph 1, 2, and "this is a link" to line up, the easiest thing to do is set the border/margin of paragraph 1 to 0, so then the two will have equal space vertical space above the text. If you want the thick border around paragraph 1, adjust the margin of the other two elements to give you the 3px space at the top.

```css
p {
   margin: 0;
}
.floatL {
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<p id="p1" class="floatL">Paragraph 1</p>
<a href="https://facebook.com" class="floatL"> This is a link </a>
<p id="p2">Paragraph 2</p>
<p>Paragraph 3</p>
```

Here's an example with the border on Paragraph 1:

```css
p {
   margin: 0;
}
#p1, #p2, a {
   border: 3px solid black;
}
#p2, a {
   border-color: transparent;
}
.floatL {
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<p id="p1" class="floatL">Paragraph 1</p>
<a href="https://facebook.com" class="floatL"> This is a link </a>
<p id="p2">Paragraph 2</p>
<p>Paragraph 3</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it even without using floats (only by applying display:inline-block to the first 3 elements):

```
<body>
<p id="p1"> Paragraph 1 </p>
<a id="a1" href="https://facebook.com">This is a link</a>
<p id="p2">Paragraph 2</p>
<p>Paragraph 3</p>
</body>
```

css:

```
#p1 { 
border: solid black 3px;
}

#p1,#a1,#p2{
display: -moz-inline-stack; 
display: inline-block; 
zoom: 1; 
*display: inline;
```

}

Here's the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/9mumaxwm/

PROs of this approach:

1) you can align the elements vertically (use vertical-align: middle or whatever)

2) you can control wrapping of the elements (by applying white-space: nowrap to the parent container)

P.S. don't let the multiple declarations of display:inline mentioned above scary you. It's a standard hack with good reputation, which works even on ancient IEs and mozillas

Answer (score 0):

if i understand what you need you just want to align the link with the text inside the paragraph..
why not to put the link inside then it will look fine:

```
<p id="p1"> Paragraph 1 <a href="https://facebook.com"> This is a link </a></p>

<p>Paragraph 2</p>
<p>Paragraph 3</p>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nra3dpvd/1/)

if you insist that it will be out side the paragraph so:

just edit your css like that:

```
p {
    float: left;
    width:100%;
}
#p1 {
    width: auto;
    margin: 0;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nra3dpvd/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/r5mvwdft/1/

Code updated as
Style

```
p{
    float:left;
    margin:0;
}
a{
    float:left;
}
#p1{
    border:2px solid black;
}
```

HTML

```
<p id="p1">Paragraph 1</p>
<a href="https://facebook.com"> This is a link </a>
<p>Paragraph 2</p>
<br/>
<p>Paragraph 3</p>
```